# Portforwarding not working

Tags: port

I recently tried to portforward port 80 on my local IP, but as the tutorial said, it should be open on my external IP, which it's not. But it is open on my local ip thought.

I have portforwarded port 80, range 80 UDP and TCP on my local IP: 192.168.1.170

This is the tutorial i followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZTYqTGqtjI

I portforwarded my IP in the router settings.

https://image.ibb.co/hGW4fm/Sk_rmbild_345.png
https://image.ibb.co/exWFmR/Sk_rmbild_344.png

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow? Did you log on to your router to do the port forwarding?

Comment: We don't have enough information here. Please give us more context

Comment: I have updated the info to be more accurate now. And I'd apprechiate if you told me if I accidentically provided to much info in any of the screenshots

Comment: Which port are you forwarding it to locally on your machine? You might not be able to use port 80 locally without admin privileges. Maybe try to set it to port 8080 locally instead.

Comment: 1: check the screenshots for more information. 2: portforwarding port 8080 didn't work either

Comment: @Trap-MixesWeekly did you turn off the anti-virus for the test on port 8080?

Answer (score 1):

IF THE suggested METHOD DOESN'T WORK FOR YOU , DO THIS :-

**GOTO -> SECURITY TAB -> REMOTE MANAGEMENT**

#### Enable the Remote Management (or enter 255.255.255.255 in the field) .

This will enable the you to access your LAN from WAN.

**For the record :-**

Internal Port is the PORT on which the device in your LAN is serving .
External Port is the port which the user enters in the browser . exp :-  127.184.184.19:8080 .
Here 8080 is the external port . And if a device in your LAN runs a http web server at port 80 , then the internal port would be 22.

If the Above methods don't work , then your ISP might be using Carrier NAT which means you would have a different PUBLIC and WAP ip address .
In this case , you should use the WAN ip address  shown in your router configuration page to access your LAN from internet.  s

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Try to open same URL from different Internet Connection other than LAN